# Is there a way 2 store factors selected by a (BE) Stepwise Regression run on N datasets via lapply(full_model, FUN(i) {step(i[[“Coeffs”]])})?

Tags: r, machine-learning, lapply, montecarlo, reproducible-research

I have already written the following code, all of which works OK:

```
directory_path <- "~/DAEN_698/sample_obs"
file_list <- list.files(path = directory_path, full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
head(file_list, n = 2)
> head(file_list, n = 2)
[1] "C:/Users/Spencer/Documents/DAEN_698/sample_obs2/0-5-1-1.csv"
[2] "C:/Users/Spencer/Documents/DAEN_698/sample_obs2/0-5-1-2.csv"

# Create another list with the just the "n-n-n-n" part of the names of of each dataset
DS_name_list = stri_sub(file_list, 49, 55)
head(DS_name_list, n = 3)
> head(DS_name_list, n = 3)
[1] "0-5-1-1" "0-5-1-2" "0-5-1-3"

# This command reads all the data in each of the N csv files via their names 
# stored in the 'file_list' list of characters.
csvs <- lapply(file_list, read.csv)

### Run a Backward Elimination Stepwise Regression on each of the N csvs.
# Assign the full model (meaning the one with all 30 candidate regressors 
# included as the initial model in step 1).
# This is crucial because if the initial model has less than the number of 
# total candidate factors for Stepwise to select from in the datasets, 
# then it could miss 1 or more of the true factors. 
full_model <- lapply(csvs, function(i) {
  lm(formula = Y ~ ., data = i) })

# my failed attempt at figuring it out myself
set.seed(50)      # for reproducibility
BE_fits3 <- lapply(full_model, function(i) {step(object = i[["coefficients"]], 
direction = 'backward', scope = formula(full_model), trace = 0)})
```

When I hit run on the above 2 lines of code after setting the seed, I get
the following error message in the Console:

```
Error in terms`(object) : object 'i' not found
```

To briefly elaborate a bit further on why it is
absolutely essential that the initial model when running a Backward Elimination
version of Stepwise Regression, consider the following example:

Let us say that we start out with an initial model of 25, so, X1:X26 instead of
X1:X30, in that case, it would be possible to miss out on Stepwise Regression j
being able to select/choose 1 or more of the IVs/factors from X26 through X30,
especially if 1 or more of those really are included in the true underlying
population model that characterizes dataset j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of two `lapply` loops, one to fit the models and the second to run the stepwise regressions, use a `for` loop doing both operations one after the other. This is an environments thing, it seems that `step` is not finding the data when run in the environment of the `lapply` function.

I have also changed the code to create `DS_name_list`. Below it processes the full names without string position dependent code.

```
DS_name_list <- basename(file_list)
DS_name_list <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(DS_name_list)
head(DS_name_list, n = 2)
```

And here is the regressions code.

```
csvs <- lapply(file_list, read.csv)
names(csvs) <- DS_name_list

set.seed(50)      # for reproducibility
full_model <- vector("list", length = length(csvs))
BE_fits3 <- vector("list", length = length(csvs))

for(i in seq_along(csvs)) {
  full_model[[i]] <- lm(formula = Y ~ ., data = csvs[[i]])
  BE_fits3[[i]] <- step(object = full_model[[i]], 
                        scope = formula(full_model[[i]]),
                        direction = 'backward',
                        trace = 0)
}
```

Comment: Wow! Your Answer has been extremely helpful in figuring out how to get around this stubborn quandary which I have been working on all day for 3 days now!

However, in order to get the final output I want, namely, a list which prints out a list formatted in the following way when you run print(list_name):
0-5-1-1, X1, X5, X6, X13, X27
as a simple example for one row of that list.
In order to achieve that, I tried the following 3 lines:
Variables_selected2 <- lapply(BE_fits3, names(i[["coefficients"]]))

Variables_selected2 <- lapply(BE_fits3, names(i[[1]][["coefficients"]]))

Comment: And also 
Variables_selected2 <- lapply(BE_fits3, names(i[[i]][["coefficients"]]))
as well which I didn't think would work, but all 3 caused the following Error message:
> Variables_selected2 <- lapply(BE_fits3, names(i[[i]][["coefficients"]]))
Error in i[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
> Variables_selected2 <- lapply(BE_fits3, names(i[[1]][["coefficients"]]))
Error in i[[1]][["coefficients"]] : subscript out of bounds
> Variables_selected2 <- lapply(BE_fits3, names(i[["coefficients"]]))
Error in i[["coefficients"]] : subscript out of bounds

Do you know to get around too?

Comment: @Spencer You are forgetting the anonymous function, `lapply(BE_fits3, \(i) etc)` but this too doesn't work. Each `i` is a `BE_fits3` list member, the names are not passed on to the anonymous function. Try `lapply(seq_along(BE_fits3), \(i) BE_fits3[[i]][["coefficients"]])`. Or better yet, whenever the object has a `"coefficients"` member, the recommended extractor is `coef(.)`. In this case, `coef(BE_fits3[[i]])`.

Comment: Ahhh, fascinating, I am/was only aware of the coefficients argument, especially in this context. I did not know there is also a coef function to try when the former is not quite up to the task at hand; I'll be back shortly to let you know if it worked!

Comment: It ended up working for mew but it takes an extremely long time for it to run, but it still does work at the end of the day, so thank you!